# How to display frame within menu options window

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a Java application using Swing.  I am using menu bar in my application.  Whenever I click a menu item I need to open a new panel/frame within the window containing menu options.

To be precise I don't want to open a new window on clicking a menu item.  What is the possible solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put windows inside of other windows, you should look at JInternalFrame:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: Aww ..shucks.  *I* was gonna' say that.  ;)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not yet solved.i need a new frame to be opened up inside the parent window.my parent window is a frame containing menu options.i want another frame/panel inside this parent window below the menu options.Thanks once again

Comment: @androidGuy Which part of JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame fails to satisfy your description?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to open a new window when clicking a menu item, [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is a good choice. Also, don't overlook the convenience of using [actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) in your [menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).